# to display one image after the another by using on click method

Tags: java, javascript, android, performance

i am having to many images in drawable folder like mickey1 and mickey 2 and mickey 3 and mickey 4;i want to draw one image after the one another to form complete mickey mouse .
 here is my code

```
    public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {
    Button next;
    ImageView  fullimage;


       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
        next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        next.setOnClickListener(this);

        fullimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullimage);


       }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int click =1;
        if (click == 1) {
             fullimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.mickey1);
             {

                 if(click==2);
                 fullimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.mickey2);

             }



    }
    }
```

}

Comment: have array of drawables. increment i on click and use the array with index i to set it to imageview

Comment: @Srinath Gopathi-just use of arraylist with adapter to find the position of image....see link-http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-displaying-images-with-an-enhanced-gallery/

Answer (score 0):

You can do initially like this

```
fullimage.setTag("1");
```

in onCreate() method.

in onClick(View v) method

```
String imageNameConst = "mickey";
int imageName = 1;
imageName = Integer.parseInt(fullimage.getTag().toString())+1;

int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imageNameConst + imageName ,"drawable",getPackageName());
fullimage.setImageResource(id);
fullimage.setTag(imageName);
```

This should work if your image names are like `mickey1, mickey2, mickey3`,....